# QML: index property of the delegate is not recognized by console.log()

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The index property of my delegate component is not recognized when it is used in `console.log()` function:

```
onClicked: {
    identities.qml_del_account(index);
    console.log(index);
}
/*Application output:*/
qrc:/Accounts2.qml:74: ReferenceError: index is not defined
```

line 74 is this:

```
console.log(index);
```

Why does it work for the first line but fails on the second? Both lines are located within the same javascript function.

Full QML code is:

```
Identities {
    id: identities
}
ListView {
            id: list_identities
            width: list_area.width
            height: 100
            model: identities
            delegate: Rectangle {
                    id: identities_delegate
                    height: 40
                    width: parent.width
                    Text {
                        id: identities_item
                        height: parent.height
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        width: 100
                        text: email
                    }
                    Image {
                        source: "qrc:/images/dots-menu.png"
                        id: toolbtn_img
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        width: 24
                        height: 24
                        MouseArea {
                            width: parent.width
                            height: parent.height
                            onClicked: {
                                identities.qml_del_account(index);
                                console.log(index);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
}
```

The model is defined in C++ and it contians the function `qml_del_account()` which works fine and I am not complaining about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is: `qml_del_account` deletes the model's entry for the current delegate, which is subsequently removed, so the log is executed on an no longer existing object model entry context.

Try to reverse the order of log and call to the model's function.

In general I would also recommend to improve the readability by referring to model data in delegates through the `model` accessor, e.g. `model.index`